# Android wheel picker

Tags: android

i just download wheel picker sample project. In that project what ever select in wheel picker it update in text view. Here i changed that text view into button, if i click that button mean it will show the value in wheel picker. its possible or not?

here my sample code:

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.test_wheel_layout);              

                bundle = new Bundle();
                wheelArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                bundle = getIntent().getExtras();               


                wheelArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) bundle.get("ItemKey");     
                wheelMenu1 = wheelArrayList.toArray(new String[wheelArrayList.size()]); 
                initWheel1(R.id.p1);            


                btnCurrentSelection = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_FrstSelection);           

                btnCurrentSelection.setText(bundle.getString("selectedValue"));                 




                btnCurrentSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        //OnWheelChangedListener();
                    }
                });

            }


        // Wheel scrolled listener
        OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener()
            {
                public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel)
                    {
                        wheelScrolled = true;
                    }

                public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel)
                    {
                        wheelScrolled = false;
                        updateStatus();
                    }
            };

        // Wheel changed listener
        private final OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener()
            {
                public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue)
                    {
                        if (!wheelScrolled)
                            {
                                updateStatus();
                            }
                    }
            };

        /**
         * Updates entered PIN status
         */
        private void updateStatus()
            {           
            PreferenceConnector.writeString(WheelActivity.this, itemKeyName, wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]);
            }           
            }

        /**
         * Initializes wheel
         * 
         * @param id
         *          the wheel widget Id
         */

        private void initWheel1(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(5);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
//              text.setText(""+wheel.getCurrentItem());
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }


        /**
         * Returns wheel by Id
         * 
         * @param id
         *          the wheel Id
         * @return the wheel with passed Id
         */
        private WheelView getWheel(int id)
            {
                return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
            }

        /**
         * Tests wheel value
         * 
         * @param id
         *          the wheel Id
         * @param value
         *          the value to test
         * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
         */
        private int getWheelValue(int id)
            {
                return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
            }
```

any one help me, how to focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i got the solution. here code

```
btnCurrentSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int id = getIndex(wheelMenu1, btnCurrentSelection.getText()
                    .toString());
            getWheel(R.id.p1).setCurrentItem(id);

        }
    });


 public int getIndex(String[] array, String specificValue) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i].equals(specificValue)) {

            return i;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```